# find if path exists in matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I must generate a 5 x 5 matrix with random values of 0s and 1s.

In such a matrix, I must find if there exists a path consisting of 1's from left to right. The adjacent 1's may be vertically, horizontally, or diagonally adjacent (also called 8-connected).

One example of success scenario is

```
1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 1 
1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 0 1 1
```

I have generated the matrix and am finding it difficult to determine a path.

I thought of checking the value of each up/down/right/diagonal index = 1 and moving on. But in such a case I dont know how to maintain a path.

Any solution / algorithm would be greatly helpful.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal A path between a 1 from the first column to a 1 in the last column. In this example one of the paths is [1][1] -> [2][2] -> [3][3]-> [3][4] -> [4][4] -> [5][5].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
The edit fixes the bugs in the previous code. Essentially, it keeps track of previously visited nodes to avoid back-tracking, and searches in all directions for possible further paths.

Using the visited nodes, it also keeps track of the actual path traversed.

```
public static boolean hasPathHelper(int[][] m, int[][] v, int i, int j){
    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= m.length || j >= m[0].length || v[i][j] >= 0)
        return false;                        // Index out of bounds

    v[i][j] = 0;                             // Mark as visited
    if(m[i][j] == 0)                         // Path stops here
        return false;
    if(j == m[0].length - 1 ||               // Right side reached!
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i - 1, j + 1) ||  // Check upper right
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i + 1, j + 1) ||  // Check lower right
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i + 1, j - 1) ||  // Check lower left
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i + 1, j - 1) ||  // Check upper left
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i + 1, j    ) ||  // Check down
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i - 1, j    ) ||  // Check up
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i    , j + 1) ||  // Check right
       hasPathHelper(m, v, i    , j - 1)     // Check left
    ) v[i][j] = 1;                           // Mark as good path

    return v[i][j] == 1;
}

public static boolean hasPath(int[][] m, int[][] v){
    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        if(hasPathHelper(m, v, i, 0))
            return true;

    return false;
}

public static void main(String... args){
    int[][] m = { {0,1,1,1,0},
                  {1,0,0,1,0},
                  {0,0,1,1,0},
                  {0,1,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,1,1,1} };

    int[][] v = new int[5][5];                         // v => -1, not visited
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)                             // v =>  0, visited bad path
        Arrays.fill(v[i], -1);                         // v =>  1, visited good path

    System.out.println("Has Path?: " + hasPath(m, v));
    System.out.println("Path Matrix: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v[i]));    
}
```

---

### Output

```
Has Path?: true
Path Matrix: 
[ 0,  1,  1, -1,  0]
[ 1,  0,  0,  1, -1]
[-1, -1,  1, -1,  0]
[-1,  1,  0,  0,  0]
[-1, -1,  1,  1,  1]
```

Comment: This misses path that double back.

Comment: @Gene Sorry, I didn't realize the OP needed that. Now it works.

Comment: It doesn't actually say what the path is... that might be a useful addition to the program.

Comment: @Floris Thanks, added your suggestion. Now it prints a matrix with {0:bad path, 1:good path, -1:not visited}

Comment: Nice addition of the solution. I would make the elements zero except for the path to take - it will be easier to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is your friend (pseudo):

```
boolean existsPath(field, from, to)
{
    if (field[from] == 0) return false;
    if (from == to) return true;
    if (existsPath(field, from + up, to)) return true;
    if (existsPath(field, from + down, to)) return true;
    if (existsPath(field, from + right, to)) return true;
    if (existsPath(field, from + diag, to)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Roughly, something like this will help you. **You will need an extra check, that prevents that you to come twice at the same point.**

Comment: That is very pseudo indeed. But you'll miss paths that go right, down, left, down, right, won't you?

Comment: He didn't specify left in his possible moves.

Comment: OP only mentions "up/down/right/diagonal" in his/her **approach**, not **the problem statement**, so it stands to reason that left moves are allowed (but I see your point). Also, it seems that OP is looking for a path from the left-most column to the right-most column (any row), so this would have to modified a bit to work, and preventing passing the same point twice is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Graph Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) algorithms.  Depth First Search is probably easiest to implement.  I will refrain from giving you code so you can learn something.  All three submitted so far are not fully correct in one way or another.

In your case, DFS will look like this (in pseudocode):

```
search(i, j, path)
  if [i,j] is off the matrix, return null
  return null if a[i,j] already marked;
  if j == 3, return path
  mark a[i,j]
  new_path = path :: <i,j> // append the pair <i,j> on the path list

  return search(i + 1, j + 1) unless its value is null
  return search(i + 1, j)     unless its value is null
  return search(i + 1, j - 1) unless its value is null

  return search(i - 1, j + 1) unless its value is null
  return search(i - 1, j)     unless its value is null
  return search(i - 1, j - 1) unless its value is null

  return search(i, j + 1) unless its value is null
  return search(i, j - 1)
```

A simple way to mark the path you have searched is change all the 1's to -1 or something similar.

Comment: Had a rough look at the Depth First Search algorithm. Not enough time to look through all of them. Will surely do so in near future.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a 2D visited `boolean` array with all `false` values with the same size as the input array.

Now check the first cell in each row of the input array.
If that cell is `1` and the corresponding visited cell is not set:

- Add that cell to a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).
- While the stack is not empty:

  - Pop from the stack.
  - If the popped cell is on the right, we've found a path.
  - Set the visited value for the popped cell to true.
  - Add all unvisited neighbours of that cell that have a value of `1` to the stack.

This is known as [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

This should also be fairly easy to do recursively (but high-level descriptions for recursive functions are slightly more difficult).